# Python web scraped HTML code do not show login form

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to login a website using Python, but in the html source code which I got for `urllib` doesn't contain a form to login and I have checked by chrome, it also shows the same html code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
            <title>cApexWEB 1.1</title>
    </head>
    <frameset border=false frameborder=0 framespacing=0>
        <frameset>
            <frame name="main" src="capexmain_middle.htm" scrolling="no" target="_top">
        </frameset>
        <noframes>
            <body>
                <p>This page uses frames, but your browser doesn\'t support them.</p>
            </body>
        </noframes>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some modern websites use dynamic content loading to load login forms from external authentication services. You may use Selenium to simulate a browser and bypass this problem. You find a detailed introduction and explanation [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: Again after login and I stuck at a page which has frames, is there some way to parse the HTML code inside the frame